# How to find the most frequent digit in array and print it

Tags: java, arrays, digit

I have this array for example:

```
|4758322| 10000 | 5748883 |2754331|
```

and I need to return the num in the array that with the most frequent digit.
in this example the method will return 10000.
Someone can help me ? I'm stuck and don't know how to begin.

thanks !

Comment: Would you like so show us some code that you've tried?

Comment: I don't get it, could you please provide more examples and explain them? There are as many 0 as 3 or 8 in your example.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the example you can see that the digit 0 is the most frequent at the array and the digit is inside the number 10000 because of this the program return the number 10000.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not provide code. So I am not going to write it either.
Try doing the following :

> For each number in the array get the modulo 10 untill value is zero.
>   you will have an int. So count the number times of each digit appears
>   in the number. Store the highest count.  repeat the procedure for
>   other numbers. And compare the counts for each. Finally display the
>   number with highest counts

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to solve a simpler version of the problem first and try to extend it to solve the entire problem.

I would try to get the frequency of digits out of one integer first, which pretty much would solve rest of your problem, something like

```
public static int maxFrequency(int number){
    int[] array = new int[(number)+"".length()];
    int max = 0;
    while(number != 0){
        array[number%10] += 1
        if(max < array[number%10]){
            max = array[number%10];
        }
        number = number/10;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Then I would use this method to extend it to all elements in the array and pick the largest.

```
int[] a = {4758322, 10000 , 5748883 ,2754331};
    int max = 0;
    int target = 0;

    for(int i : a){

        int maxFrequencyi = maxFrequency(i);
        if(max < maxFrequencyi){
            max = maxFrequencyi;
            target = i;
        }
    }
  return target;
```

Comment: Looks like you are new, next time try working on it and use google to search for ideas and then post your code snippet in the question if you are still not able to solve the problem, that would tell people that you have tried solving the problem and help people understand the problem better .